# Removing NAs from column while calculating the length of it

Tags: r

So i've got a column in dataframe for 237 different pulses, and from those i gotta take pulses that are over 100 and less than 45, and see how many of them there are. I know that i can get the lenght of that with

```
length(survey$Pulse[survey$Pulse > 100 | survey$Pulse < 45])
```

However there are NA values in the column and i got no idea how to remove those from the lenght.

If you need more info ill try to provide but the only thing i dont know how to do is removing NA values from the column.

I know i could use `na.rm=TRUE` but i got no idea how to implement it to the line.

Comment: use `na.omit() `; `length(na.omit(survey$Pulse[survey$Pulse > 100 | survey$Pulse < 45]))`

Comment: Thank you! This is just my 2nd time of coding R and I have no idea how to use it properly. That helped alot, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `na.omit` - it returns object with `NA` values removed.

For example:

```
# With na.omit
length(na.omit(c(1:10, NA)))
10
# Without na.omit
length(c(1:10, NA))
11
```

In your case use:

```
length(na.omit(survey$Pulse[survey$Pulse > 100 | survey$Pulse < 45]))
```

Comment: Also, I think they should use `sum` instead of `length` for this sort of thing, so maybe `sum(cond, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: Or `length(sort(c(1:10, NA)))`

Comment: `which` is fastest of the three.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to wrap `which` around the logical condition. When there are `NA` values present, the logical condition is not enough. I'll give an example with fake data.

```
x <- c(1:3, NA, 4, NA, 5:7, NA, 8:10)
x[x < 4 | x > 7]
#[1]  1  2  3 NA NA NA  8  9 10

x[which(x < 4 | x > 7)]
#[1]  1  2  3  8  9 10
```

And the `length` is obviously different.